# VNA reflection and transmission of stripline stub

Tags: antenna, transmission-line, microstrip, reflection, vna

Testing this stub board. 
I understand S12 is attenuated at 1.79GHz due L=λ/4. 
So I calculate relative permitivity:

ε<sub>r</sub> = (c / 4Lf)<sup>2</sup> = 3.3

But what does (ε<sub>r</sub>) represent in a physics perspective? Is it permitivity of the board dielectric? If so how does the signal interact with the ground plane in this stub?

Second: What is the cause of the reduced S11 reflection at 3.09GHz?

[image: VNA]

Comment: The εr you have calculated is the effective permittivity. it's not the board's (FR4) permittivity because the wave doesn't 'see' a homogeneous material - it sees air on the top.

Comment: But, to add to what Mike says, the "upper half" of the space it sees has lower relative permittivity, by a factor of >4, so most field energy will be below.

Comment: Then what does _effective permittivity_ represent? How is the signal being slowed down?

Comment: Is velocity = sqrt(L/C) ?